# How do I check file contain and rename it using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have many files in a folder. The file name looks like this

```
12AB34-A1.txt
12AB34-AE.txt
12AB34-P1.txt
12AB34-ZS.txt
```

I want to check the file in the folder exist or not, then I pick one of the file then rename it.

I tried with this code, but it still gives me error.

```
if (Test-Path -Path "C:\Users\SS\Work\*.txt") {
    Write-Host "Job.cue File is exist"
    $Pro = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\SS\Work | Where-Object{$_.Contains("-A1")}
    $Pro
    Rename-Item $Pro -NewName ($Pro.BaseName).ini
    Write-Host "Rename Finished"
}
```

Comment: What error does it give you?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change that to

```
$Pro = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\SS\Work | Where-Object{$_.Name -like "*-A1*")}
```

You still have to account for the fact that `$pro` can have multiple results.

So you might want to enclose this in a `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($f in $pro)
{
    Rename-Item $f -NewName ($f.BaseName).ini
}
```

Comment: The second code snippet will still fail b/c `$f` is not expanded to the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might make it easier to keep track of what's happening:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\path\to\folder\containing\files

foreach ($file in $files){
    if ($file.BaseName -like "*-A1*"){
        Write-Host "Currently renaming: $($file.Name) "
        $newName = $file.BaseName + ".ini"
        Rename-Item $file.FullName -NewName $newName
    }else{
        #Do nothing since files doesn't have '-A1' in its name
    }
}
```

Comment: If your `else` branch does nothing there is no reason for having it in the first place.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Just leaving it open to options :)

Answer (score 0):

`$Pro` in the rename statement expands to the filename only (`$Pro.Name`) rather than the full path (`$Pro.FullName`), so the statement doesn't find the file in your current working directory. Also, `Contains()` must be called on a property of the file objects (e.g. `$_.Name.Contains('-A1')`), not on directly on the objects.

You can fix the issue by changing

```
Rename-Item $Pro -NewName ($Pro.BaseName).ini
```

to

```
Rename-Item $Pro.FullName -NewName ($Pro.BaseName).ini
```

However, your code makes the implicit assumption that the `Get-ChildItem` will return only a single result. It will break when the statement returns more than one item, because `Rename-Item` accepts only a single source path.

A better approach to the issue is to feed the `Get-ChildItem` results directly into `Rename-Item` via the pipeline:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\SS\Work' -Filter '*-A1*' |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + '.ini' }
```

That takes care of the path issue as well as multiple results.